# WebSphere Email Adapter 6.1.x (any known memory leaks)

Tags: email, websphere, adapter

Is there any known memory leaks in the WebSphere email adapter 6.1.x version?

I can't seem to find any based on my search on IBM site and Google searches.

Here is the situation:

On one server, the WPS admin folks say OOM errors occur because of this email adapter while the same stuff works on 2 more servers. I don't have access to the heap dumps (as the admins are not sharing them with me and I have limited access to the servers)

Appreciate any suggestions.

I am asking them for the heap dumps but while waiting for that what else can I try? One possibility is to shutdown the email adapter components and observe but that might not account for the differences in the behaviour across multiple servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a preproduction or stress/volume testing platform, I would create a load test that would specifically target the bits using Email Adapter and put through traffic (possibly using a tool like [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)) that test it to breaking point.  If the server doesn't OOM, then the indications are that your leak is somewhere else.

However, the most productive thing would probably be to wait for the heap dumps... (good luck)

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I got the heap dumps and i can't see the reason why this occurs. The heap dump does identify who is the culprit. I can see a huge number of objects being created each of small size 2K (but a zillion of them) which is the culprit. This is actually the javax.mail.InternetHeader and i can't see any reason why those many headers are created.